# Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins

Tags: react-native, expo

I created React native using EXPO .Once I run the project I get following error.I have not done any coding on the project.Just a plain project

**iOS Bundling failed 2610ms
App.js: /Users/kasun/Desktop/test-site/weather-app/App.js: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins**

Answer (score 4):

Make sure tailwind CSS is installed at 3.3.2 and not ^3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Tailwindcss version 3.3.3 and use tailwind@3.3.2 and that should fixed the problem.

I did same thing and it worked.